# We make fresh soymilk and gypsum How and why does my silken tofu turn mushy and not jelly like?

Tags: texture, tofu, pudding

We make fresh soymilk and gypsum to make silken tofu or toffu pudding.How and why does my silken tofu turn mushy and not jelly like? What is the temperature the milk has to have for it to be ready to be poured in with coagulant?